# Discord bot not able to ping Minecraft server for information

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When running the bot command in the Discord server, it says unable to ping the server and I do not know how to fix it. Please help (also got this from a template) I'm not sure why it doesn't work or if I'm doing something wrong.

code:

```js
const { Client, Intents, Message} = require('discord.js');
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
const {EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const options = {
    timeout: 1000 * 5, 
    enableSRV: true 
};
const prefix = "!mcstatus"; 
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages",
        "MessageContent"
    ]
});
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot started');
    
    client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: `${server_ip}`, type: 'WATCHING' }], status: 'active' });
});
const server_ip = "mc.hypixel.net"; 
const server_port = 25565; 
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
          util.status(server_ip, server_port, options)
    .then((result) => {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#FF0000")
    .setTitle("example server status")
    .setDescription(`This will show the status and info about the minecraft server \n **Server ip:** ${server_ip} \n **Server port:** ${server_port}`)
    .addFields(
        {name:"Server Version", value: `${result.version.name}`},
        {name:"Server Protocol Version", value:`${result.version.protocol}`},
        {name:"Players Online", value:`${result.players.online}`},
        {name:"Max Players", value:`${result.players.max}`},
        {name:"MOTD (May Not Display Accurately)", value:`${result.motd.clean}`},
        {name:"Latency", value:`${result.roundTripLatency}`},
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    })
    
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("#808080")
    .setTitle("example server status")
    .setDescription(`The server was unable to be pinged or you mis-typed the info`)
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    
    })}});
client.login("token");
```

I have tried searching online for fixes but all of them are for older versions that no longer work.

log:

```
PS C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test> node .
bot started
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected 'options' to be an object or undefined, got number
    at C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:46:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:4:12)
    at status (C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:40:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:113:17)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\jason\Documents\discord minecraft bot test\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Comment: Both to debug this yourself and to help us help you, you should create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try doing whatever it is you're trying to do without all the extra stuff (like the Discord-related things) making it messy it and see if it still happens. That would help you zone in on the heart of the problem and likely give you an idea of how to solve it.

Comment: I guess that you have an older version of that module installed, the older one used `options` as a second argument

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code you provided it works just fine, I believe you have installed an older version of this package.

Please try running `npm install minecraft-server-util@latest` to install the latest version of this package and try running it again.